# SubSonic column named 'Key'

Tags: sql, mysql, subsonic, subsonic3, subsonic-simplerepository

I have a column named 'Key' in a MySQL database. Seems that the

```
repo.Find<Class>(x=>x.Key.StartsWith("BLAH"));
```

generates the SQL code

```
WHERE Key LIKE 'BLAH%'
```

instead of the correct one like

```
WHERE `Key` LIKE 'BLAH%'
```

How can I force the later behaviour (is it a bug in SubSonic?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the latest source from git - this is a bug that was resolved since releasing 3.0.0.4

Comment: Hi! Can you point me to a specific commit? 8a3f14d8e21409ddf390581aefedf07393eb990a seems to have the same issue: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Key LIKE 'S%'' at line 3

Comment: You're right the issue is not fixed for MySQL. I'll take a look!